# Several bots in one app

Tags: laravel, telegram-bot

I create telegram bot with laravel and [sdk](https://telegram-bot-sdk.readme.io/docs). All work good. How can I add another bot in same app? In `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php` I add

```
protected $except = [
'437198700:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_YYYYY/webhook'
];
```

for first bot. And in `app/config/telegram.php`

```
'bot_token' => '437198700:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX_YYYYY',
```

Up. I add this to config but still same problem

```
`return [

//    'default' => 'common',


    'bots' => [
        'common' => [
            'username'  => 'MyTelegramBot',
            'token' => env('TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN'),
            'commands' => [
//                Acme\Project\Commands\MyTelegramBot\BotCommand::class
            ],
        ],
        'second' => [
            'username'  => 'MySecondBot',
            'token' => env('TELEGRAM_MANAGER_BOT_TOKEN'),
        ],
    ],
```

Upd: I add this `$bots_manager= new BotsManager($config);` $config look like [config](http://joxi.ru/v29neVXtG9dYaA) I try to call `$bots_manager = $bots_manager->bot('second');` Return error `Bot [second] not configured.` What I do wrong?

Comment: Ask author instead of asking here.

Comment: If you look at [telegram.php config file](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/master/src/Laravel/config/telegram.php) you can see `'bots' => [...`. Use that to add multiple bots. I also don't see `bot_token` there...

Comment: @ljubadr I edit my config like in example but still have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply put it as an array in my `telegram.php` config:

```
'bot_tokens' => [
    TOKEN1,
    TOKEN2,
    // Other bot tokens here
]
```

Then in my `VerifyCsrfToken.php` file, the `$excluded` variable will be:

```
protected $excluded = [
    BOT_ROUTE1,
    BOT_ROUTE2,       
];
```

I am curious to know what are you looking for in the app with multiple telegram bots?

Comment: When I do this, message to which second bot comes to first bot.

Comment: You need to add a middleware to check which message is intended for which bot.

Answer (score 0):

use a [BotManager](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/master/src/BotsManager.php)

you should create Bot class instance for each bot. then manage bot by name or token with BotManager methods.

it's my Python3 example, but it similar issue

```
class Bot(Resource):

    bots = {}

    def __init__(self, token):
        self.updater = Updater(token)
        self.bots[token] = self

    @classmethod
    def getInstance(cls, token):
        return cls.bots[token]

    def start_bot(self):
        self.updater.start_polling()

    def stop_bot(self):
        self.updater.stop()


#####################################

bots = Bots.query.all()
if bots:
    for bot in bots:
        tb = Bot(bot.token)
        tb.start_bot()

bot = Bot.getInstance(bot.token)
bot.stop_bot()
```

Comment: `$bots_manager= new BotsManager($config);` what put into `$config`?

Comment: bot credential. see example from [sdk](https://github.com/irazasyed/telegram-bot-sdk/blob/master/src/Laravel/config/telegram.php)  

`'bots' => [
        'common' => [
            'username'  => 'MyFirstBot',
            'token' => '123456:abc',
            ],
        ],
        'second' => [
            'username'  => 'MySecondBot',
            'token' => '123456:abc',
        ],
    ],`